# Delphi - настройки формы

Tags: delphi

Как в Delphi задать тип прозрачности формы (не использую AlhaBlend). И ещё, как у формы удалить границы?

Answer (score 1):

Даже не используя AlhaBlend ниже, чем Windows2000 (или XP, не помню уже), оно работать не будет. По поводу границы:

```
SetWindowRgn(Handle, CreateRectRgn(2,2,Width - 2, Height - 2), True)
```

Comment: По поводу границы: есть вариант попроше 
Form1.border:=none